# CSS Positioning Image to re-size with window

Tags: html, css, image, css-position

I am new to HTML and CSS, but I want to have an image span the entire header without cutting out part of the image, or being a fixed size. Currently, the entire image does not show up, and when the window is re-sized, part of the image is cropped out. I want the window to be adjustable, and when it is, the image adjusts with it to show the entire image.

Here is the CSS for my header. Also, my page layout is that the header is only contained in a div call "page" and the rest of the content is nested in "page" as "content".

```
 #header {
    background-image: url("../images/header.jpg");
    background-position: right;
    background-size: 100%;  
    width: 100%;
    height: 20%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    transform: translateX(-50%);
}
```

Comment: Can we get the css for `#page` and `body`?
I'm guessing that `#page` has some type of margin or max-width set on it constraining `#header` and `#content`?

Also, why are you transforming your `#header` left by 50% using translate instead of just setting `left: 0`?

Answer (score 1):

Make your image an HTML element `<img>` - rather than a background - it will be easier to get the effect you desire with less code.

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  }
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: fixed;
}
img {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <img src="http://placehold.it/1000x150">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, the height kind of sucks for what I want though. Having a auto height makes it way to big in some cases, where it takes up almost eh entire screen.  However, the fixed height doesn't adjust with the width so the image becomes distorted.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using `background-image` with padding to 'fake' the div height.

```css
 body {
   margin: 0;
 }
#header {
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: fixed;
    background-image: url("http://placehold.it/1000x150");
    background-size: contain;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    height: 0;
    padding-top: 15%; /* (img-height / img-width * width) */ /* (150 / 1000 * 100) */
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
</div>
```

**EDIT:** 
If cropping is ok you can try [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/YXpZxZ).

Comment: Thank you, this did fix the issue of the image being able to re-size. However, it takes up a large portion of the screen as I expanded the width of the screen. At full screen it was probably 90%. I was using 350px as my height and 35% as the top padding.

Comment: Width is explicitly linked to height, changing one means changing the other... unless you are prepared to distort or crop, I added a cropped version to my post in case that helps.